# Need help in Android Programming regarding ListActivity under tab

Tags: android, listactivity

I'm trying to embed listactivity inside Tab. but when i run the application. It stop working and force me to close the app. Take a look to program in below link:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16910648/RazzilCity.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code. Just two mistakes I found, In your `Manifest.xml` and in `Places.java`.
In your `Manifest` file you have defined `City Activity` two times.
Just remove the the line

```
<activity android:name=".City" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```

and in your `Place.java`,
just replace the line

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.places_list,PLACES));
```

by

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,PLACES));
```

Comment: Thanks Adil, working perfect. Could please tell me more about why you put android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of R.layout.places_list ??

Comment: [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) is responsible to display the list row as well as the list data, So it needs a `Context`, `TextView` and array, You can pass the id of `TextView` of your own, or you can use built in `TextView` (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`)